# Hardware implementations for a low-cost ADC array project

Tags: arduino, audio, adc, beaglebone, beamforming

I wonder what would be the best hardware platform or architecture for implementing and building a lowish-cost system to sample audio capture over a large array of microphones or sensors? say, 300 or 500 audio channels simultaneously, and be able to transmit the information either via USB or Ethernet

Comment: That sounds like a fun project. Do you mind sharing some more about what you're *actually* trying to do? Is it related to [beamforming](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2i293tUjYbI)? Is it ultra-sound? Is the bandwidth gap narrow (maybe you only care about 3 kHz to 5 kHz)? - Elaborate, the more information you share, the easier it will be for us to guide you to a good solution. - The answers that are usually best received are the ones that describe their wanted end result.

Comment: I wish that a canonical answer encompassed both sound and ultra-sound suggestions for beamforming purposes

Comment: @lurscher - One more time - "Do you mind sharing some more about what you're actually trying to do?"

Comment: @lurscher Ah great, it's related to beamforming. That's **awesome** information! Is your array in a 2D-array? 1D-array? **There are so many (missing) parameters**. - If you want a canonical answer, then you should expect no answer and then place a bounty of 100 on it. If you want an answer that is related to what you're trying to do then you should be as specific as a child making a wish to Santa Clause.

Comment: Probably a bunch of i2s based codecs or microphones connected to an FPGA or bank of FPGA's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "lowish cost system" when you are talking about data acquisition of 300 to 500 audio-bandwidth signals. This is out of scope for an Arduino or even a Beaglebone. You probably have to start looking into some serious hardware with an FPGA in it (e.g., a Zynq board).

For starters, data transfer bandwidth is an issue. At a minimum nyquist frequency for a <10KHz bandwidth signal you have 300 channels * 16 bits * 20000 S/s = 96Mb/s. That will require Gb ethernet and will saturate PC USB ports without a dedicated software driver (forget about the serial drivers used by Arduino boards, for example, I saturate those with just 2Mb/s).

Then, as you are considering a beam-forming application, you would have to seriously consider simultaneous sampling. That is, all of your ADC channels synchronized and sampling at the same time, otherwise you would need additional signal processing. That makes finding the proper ADCs and dividing the problem into multiple low-channel count modules more difficult (e.g., 10 BeagleBone boards at 30 channels each).

Next, is the data acquisition front-end and signal conditioning. You can find 8-channel simultaneously sampling ADCs with some specific signal conditioning relatively easily, but if you need to add conditioning circuitry to each individual channel you are talking about a lot of passives. Also, you would be hard-pressed to drive two of these ADCs out of a single simple serial port such as SPI, you would need faster interfaces and, very likely, multiple individual communication channels.

And last, but not least, comes the software to handle all those channels in real time. Modern-day PCs can do it, but they will struggle (forget about Matlab, Python or other similar languages, you need C#/C++/Swift or other languages that compile as close to bare metal as possible).

---

My advise, divide the problem into separate low-channel count modules (e.g., 16 to 64) that can be replicated easily. Design a controller board that can drive multiple modules at the same time. Use Ethernet, USB's master-slave architecture makes it problematic, Ethernet drivers are designed for speed.

Comment: The samples do NOT need to be synchronized as long as the exact time of each sample is known or can be recovered somehow.

Comment: @mkeith theoretically true, but have you considered the additional signal processing load required to compensate for all of those unnecessary delays? I prefer the front-end to avoid the problem altogether.

Comment: It really depends on what the OP wants to do. If the time offset is known, and if DSP is involved anyway, it is no big deal to re-sample the signal with a slight delay. Not an expert on DSP. But I have had many conversations with DSP experts when talking about radar imaging.

Comment: It would only be "extra" signal processing if FFT's were not going to be involved to begin with. But I don't think the beamforming will work very well if you discretize the time shifting to whole sample periods. So the data will have to be resampled anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think the lowest cost you are going to achieve will be with some type of i2s-based adc. For example, Knowles has a "digital microphone" module with a microphone, amplifier, and i2s ADC all-in-one.

The only way to handle 100's of channels of i2s (that I know of) will be to feed them to an FPGA or bank of FPGA's. Depending on what you are doing, it may be able to at least partially process the data in the FPGA to reduce the badnwidth that comes out of the FPGA. Otherwise, you may run into a bandwidth limit to whatever processor or DSP you pass the data to. If you want to preserve all the channels so that you can go back in time and beam-form on data after the fact, you will need to store a lot of data!

I believe that arrays like this already exist. I am pretty sure I saw something like that in a basketball stadium. They had an array of microphones in the middle of stadium on the roof with cameras. The beam forming worked in conjunction with the camera so they could zoom in on anyone in the stadium and beamform to also eavesdrop on their conversation. Creepy!